# Why do functions that call by reference not work when they are linked from other source files in a mex wrapper?

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I have written two functions 'refFunc' and 'valFunc' in two seperate .c files with header files.  I attempted to compile them along with a mex wrapper function 'mainmex' and link them together to form a mex executable.  The function 'refFunc' takes an 'int' and returns that integer multiplied by 2.  The function 'valFunc' does the same thing, only it calls by reference instead of calling by value and it doesn't return anything.  'valFunc' executes just fine, but 'refFunc' causes an access violation.

As a sanity check, I repeated the same steps with a "vanilla" c wrapper 'mainc'.  The function executed just fine without any problems.  Is there some quirk in Matlab that is causing this?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code for mainmex.c

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "valFunc.h"
#include "refFunc.h"
#include <stdio.h>


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    printf("executing valFunc, answer is %i\n", valFunc((int)5));
    int *b;
    *b = 0;
    printf("executing valFunc, ...");
    refFunc((int)5, b);
    printf("b is %i\n", *b);
}
```

And for refFunc.c

```
#include "refFunc.h" /*Doesn't seem to make a difference whether or not I 
                     include the header file*/
void refFunc(int a, int *b)
{
    *b = 2 * a;
}
```

And for valFunc.c

```
#include "valFunc.h" /*Doesn't seem to make a difference whether or not I 
                     include the header file*/
int valFunc(int a)
{
    int b = a * 2;
    return b;
}
```

And for refFunc.h

```
void refFunc(int a, int *b);
```

And for valFunc.h

```
int valFunc(int a);
```

And for mainc.c

```
#include "valFunc.h"
#include "refFunc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("executing valFunc, answer is %i\n", valFunc((int)5));
    int *b;
    *b = 0;
    printf("executing valFunc, ...");
    refFunc((int)5, b);
    printf("b is %i\n", *b);
}
```

And finally, the command I am using to compile and run the mex and the output I got

```
>> mex refFunc.c valFunc.c -c
Building with 'MinGW Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
>> mex mainmex.c refFunc.obj valFunc.obj
Building with 'MinGW Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
>> mainmex
executing valFunc, answer is 10
executing valFunc, ...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Thu
```

When I switched to bash, I did the following and got the following:

```
$ gcc mainc.c valFunc.obj refFunc.obj -fno-use-linker-plugin
$ ./a.exe
executing valFunc, answer is 10
executing valFunc, ...b is 10
```

Notice how I even used the same .obj files that were left over from my work in matlab.

Comment: This has nothing in specifically to do with Matlab or mex.  That's just the setting in which the problem was encountered.  Tags edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mexFunc()` declares a pointer, and fails to initialize it.  This pointer's value is indeterminate.  You then pass this pointer to `refFunc()`, which attempts to write its result to the (indeterminate) location to which the pointer points.  This exhibits undefined behavior.

`mexFunction()` should instead do this:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int b;                   // declare b as int, not int *
    refFunc((int)5, &b);     // pass the address of b
    printf("b is %i\n", b);  // b's value has been set
}
```

Note also that C has neither references as a variety of data type nor pass-by-reference call semantics.  All C function calls are pass-by-value; in some cases, such as this one, arguments are pointers (which are passed by value).

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Actually, in the OP's original code he declares the uninitialized pointer b and then tries to dereference it with `*b=0;` This could easily crash right there, before getting to the call to refFunc().

Comment: Right you are, @FredK.  I have updated my answer to describe the situation more accurately, though no change to the recommended correction is required.